# "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt." Delphi7 DLL from C#

Tags: c#, delphi, dll

I am facing a problem calling a Delphi 7 DLL file from C#. I am new to C# and don't know Delphi that much and I don't need to really knows that much. I just need to get this problem solved as soon as possible.

I am trying to call the dll from C# but I get this error : "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."

And I have no clue why it is happening . As you will see in my Delphi code , I'm not trying to return any value . I just need to send some commands on the COM port. Please if anyone can help me out of here :(

**Delphi DLL code:**

```
library Project2;


uses
  SysUtils,
  ComPort,
  Classes;

var com1:TComport ;

{$R *.res}
procedure moveforward; export;
begin
  com1.WriteAnsiString('#20 P1528 CR'+sLineBreak);
  com1.WriteAnsiString('#7 P1465 CR'+sLineBreak);
end;

procedure movebackward; export;
begin
  comport1.WriteAnsiString('#7 P1528 CR'+sLineBreak);
  comport1.WriteAnsiString('#20 P1465 CR'+sLineBreak);
end;

procedure stopmove;export;
begin
  comport1.WriteAnsiString('#20 P1500 CR'+sLineBreak);
  comport1.WriteAnsiString('#7 P1500 CR'+sLineBreak);
end;

procedure catch; export;
begin
  comport1.WriteAnsiString('#2 P2120 T2000 CR'+sLineBreak); //arm
  comport1.WriteAnsiString('#30 P2260 T500 CR'+sLineBreak); //gripper
end;

procedure initialize; export;
begin
  comport1.WriteAnsiString('#2 P2184 T1000 CR'+sLineBreak); //arm
  comport1.WriteAnsiString('#30 P1980 T2000 CR'+sLineBreak); //gripper
end;

exports  
  moveforward, movebackward, stopmove, catch, initialize;

begin
end.
```

**C# Code**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("Project2.dll")]
        public static extern void moveforward();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            moveforward();
        }
    }
}
```

Any help will be truly appreciated

Comment: surely you can do this with pure C# and thus avoid the pinvokes and extra native module

Answer (score 7):

EDIT:

Please note, upon further reflection I'm pretty sure this is not the right answer. It's still a **bad idea** to use mismatched calling conventions (thus my initial instinct that it was the problem) but in this case it is probably not the cause of the GPF.

ORIGINAL:

99% of the time, this error means you got the calling conventions wrong. It's been a while since I wrote in Delphi but I think this will fix your problem:

```
procedure moveforward; export; stdcall;
```

The [calling convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) is normally not an issue when you're only using a single compiler, because everything uses the same one. It can be a problem when you mix languages, or even if you mix different vendor's compilers. The calling convention determines which end of the call has to clean up parameters; if both sides try to do that it's likely to cause a GPF.

By default, the [`DllImport`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.callingconvention.aspx) attribute uses a calling convention of `CallingConvention.StdCall`, though you can override that in the attribute itself. Unfortunately, Delphi's default calling convention is a type that isn't supported (alternatively called fastcall or register), so your only option is to change the Delphi side to use stdcall.

Comment: +1. You might want to edit to explain that the `stdcall` should be added to all exported procedure declarations (since the asker has specifically said they're unfamiliar with Delphi).

Comment: **Extremely** nice edit. :) I'd give it an extra +1 if I could. (I'd only change the words "unfortunately" and "not supported", because `fastcall` or `register` is the best choice under most circumstances when you're programming native Win32 apps - you could say that Microsoft's choice of `stdcall` as the default was "unfortunate" because it's not as efficient as `fastcall` when not being used in a certain way.) Delphi's primary use is developing stand-alone, self-contained Win32 executables, and that target functions most efficiently using `fastcall` or `register` calling convention. :)

Comment: Although it's important to get calling conventions right, it shouldn't be a cause of problems in this case. When there are no function arguments, the stdcall and register calling conventions are identical.

Comment: "Unfortunate" only in that .NET doesn't support fastcall/register, so you can't do the more obvious option and fix your import to match the Delphi export.

Comment: All this talk of calling conventions is very interesting but completely irrelevant to a question concerning procedures without parameters.

Comment: true; any time I see P/Invoke throw a GPF I always assume the calling conventions are wrong, and in this case they were, but you are right that I wasn't paying enough attention to the actual signature being called. Updating my answer.

Answer (score 5):

The Delphi code never assigns a value to the global `com1` variable. You need to make it refer to a `TComport` instance. Export another function that sets up the DLL for further use:

```pas
procedure set_up_dll; stdcall; export;
begin
  com1 := TComport.Create(nil);
end;
```

Have another one that destroys it:

```pas
procedure clean_up_dll; stdcall; export;
begin
  com1.Free;
  com1 := nil;
end;
```

Call those functions before and after using the other functions of the DLL.

Comment: THANKS A LOT.I'LL TRY IT TONIGHT TO SEE WHAT WILL HAPPEN :)